# Can I create a new Windows group on windows using Java

Tags: java, windows, spring, security

I need to be able to create a new group on windows, this group will be added to the ACL permissions on many different files and folders and I will add and remove users from that group as needed. 
Each User will exist however ideally I need the end user to have no involvement in the creation or maintenance of the windows group. 
I am using Java 8, ideally I dont want to shell out, does anyone know of any Java libraries or have any experience as to if or how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Note: not really relevant but the windows user to be added is currently being fetched via:

```
UserPrincipal windowsUser = FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService()
      .lookupPrincipalByName("some.name");
```

Comment: Cheers for the down-vote, very helpful! Would really like some feedback IE is this something that is possible to do or will I have to go to shell?

Answer (score 0):

> ideally I need the end user to have no involvement in the creation or
>   maintenance of the windows group

So create a web service that does the work on request.

> I need to be able to create a new group on windows

<del>This isn't posible with plain Java.</del> (That isn't true [since Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclEntry.html))

Probably you can use [Runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) in your service to execute a commandline with [calcs.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/cc732245(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Hi, yes I have been able to do this in command line which indeed DOES work to create a group however the powers be are very unhappy and whilst they will accept this if there is no other option they want me to be sure that there is no library in Java to create windows groups first, I have not seen or heard of any so just wanted to double check with some of the experts in this field :-)